# how do I solve "Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'" for database-js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

While using database-js I have run into this error, I have spent the better part of the day trying to figure out what to install or include. I have tried node-mysql, mysql, @cubejs-backend\mysql-driver, and database-js-mysql. I have also tried using require('mysql') but I am running it in a browswer environment using react so I cant get it to work.

```
import * as databaseJS from "database-js";

export function TableCommand(sql) {
    var result;

    
    const db = new databaseJS.Connection({
        DriverName: "mysql",
        Username: "admin",
        Password: "...",
        Hostname: "localhost",
        Database: "..."
    });

    var command = db.prepareStatement(sql); 

    command.query(sql)
        .then((results)=> {
            result = results;
            db.close()
            .then(() => {
                process.exit(0);
            }).catch((reason) => {
                console.log(reason);
                process.exit(1)
            });
        }).catch((reason) => {
            console.log(reason); // Some problem while performing the query
            db.close() // Close the connection
                .then(() => {
                    process.exit(0); // Success!
                }).catch((reason) => {
                    console.log(reason); // Some problem when closing the connection
                    process.exit(1);
                });
        });

    return result;     
}'''
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO; these modules are not designed to work on the browser and only on Node. You will then have to create a server (in Node) to serve the database results either via REST or GraphQL for React to then request and present on the browser.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any recommendations on where to start? I have experience with react and with mysql however, I have mothing in the way of doing them together. The only time I would've gotten the experience I was in a group and my partner handled the database part where I just did front end work.

Comment: There are many tutorials, blog posts, videos and boilerplates to get started but I personally would follow this: https://bezkoder.com/react-node-express-mysql/ while it may not be the exact project you're looking to build it will give you an idea on how to  get  things working which you can adapt to your requirements.